# Flutter POST API response 500 with Body:- {"message":"array_shift() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given","data":""}

Tags: flutter, api, post

**Error is: - 500 Body:- {"message":"array_shift() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given","data":""} **

If i am sending blank body than response is 200 but when i am sending data in body so response is this: 500 with Body:- {"message":"array_shift() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given","data":""} **

---

```
   Dashboard(start, length) async {
        FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
        setState(() {
          this.isLoading = true;
        });
        await ApiWrapper.DashData(
          start: start,
          length: length,
          date_var: _range,
          project: Project,
          city_list: CityItem.toString(),
          emp: "",
          condition: Stages,
          vendor: ""
        ).then((response) {
          if (response.message != null) {
            DashboardDataResponse = response;
            if (start == 0 && length == 10) {
              DashboardData = _DashboardDataResponse?.data;
            } else {
              DashboardDataResponse?.data?.forEach((element) {
                DashboardData?.add(element);
              });
            }
          } else {
            print(response.message);
          }
          isLoading = false;
          setState(() {});
        }).catchError((error) {
          setState(() {
            isLoading = false;
          });
        });
      }
```

---

**api_wrapper**

```
static Future<DashboardDataResponse> DashData(
      {required int length, required int start,
        String? date_var,
  String? project,
  String? city_list,
  String? emp,
 String? condition,
  String? vendor,
 }) async {
    var response = await ApiService.Dashboard(
        length: length, start: start, project_name_list: project_name_list,cityId_list: cityId_list,
        presales_emp: presales_emp, condition:condition, vendor: vendor,
        );
    return response;
  }
```

---

**API.dart**

```
 static Future<DashboardDataResponse> Dashboard({
    int? length,
    int? start, String? project, String? date_var,
    String? city_list, String? condition,
    String? vendor, String? vendor, String? emp,
  }) async {
    var body = {
      "requestHeader": requestHeader,
      "start": start,
      "length": length,
      "date_var": date_var,
      "project": project,
      "city_list": city_list,
      "emp": emp,
      "condition": condition,
      "vendor": vendor,
     
    };
    var response = await HttpMethods.post(ApiUrl.Dashboard, body);
    return DashboardDataParser.parser(response);
  }
```

---

**Error is: - 500 Body:- {"message":"array_shift() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given","data":""} **

Comment: Please pass  jsonEncode(body)  instead of body

Comment: its not working with jsonEncode(body) an the response is same 500 array_shift() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given

Comment: returning same  error ?